# edit an xml file - search values taken from a file, replacement values taken from a second file. Search must be case insensitive

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have as source, something like below:

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
<TABLE NAME="TEST">
<DATA RECORDS="78">
<catalog>
   <book id="bk109">
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <description>An anthology of HORROR stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk113">
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk114">
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep PROGRAMMER's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk115">
      <description>An anthology of HORROR stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk116">
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk114">
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep PROGRAMMER's reference. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
   </book>
</DATA>
</TABLE>
```

search.txt file contains:

```
An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.
Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.
```

replace.txt file contains:

```
Value we need to store in the (description) element.
Another value we need to store in the (description) element.
```

The search should be case insensitive,

so both

```
<description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
```

and

```
<description>An anthology of HORROR stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
```

should be matched, and replaced, so the result xml should look like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<TABLE NAME="TEST">
<DATA RECORDS="78">
<catalog>
   <book id="bk109">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <description>Another value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk113">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk114">
      <description>Another value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk115">
      <description>Value we need to store in the (description) element.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk116">
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk114">
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep PROGRAMMER's reference. Beware, this must not be matched.</description>
   </book>
</DATA>
</TABLE>
```

i have tried with http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/ with no luck, and i have to mention, that special characters may be found in the search or replacement value, like a ., pareentheses(), etc, and an exact match (case insensitive ofcourse) is needed in order for the replacement to take place, please see the last description node, that is not replaced.

UPDATE:
what i have tried, and does not work, if the replacement string is not a single word:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="search-file" as="xs:string" select="'search.txt'"/>
    <xsl:param name="replacement-file" as="xs:string" select="'replace.txt'"/>


    <xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($search-file), '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term))"/>

    <xsl:param name="replace-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($replacement-file), '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:include href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>

    <xsl:function name="functx:replace-multi" as="xs:string?"
        xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
        <xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>
        <xsl:param name="changeFrom" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="changeTo" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="flags" as="xs:string"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="
            if (count($changeFrom) > 0)
            then functx:replace-multi(
            replace($arg, $changeFrom[1],
            functx:if-absent($changeTo[1],''), $flags),
            $changeFrom[position() > 1],
            $changeTo[position() > 1])
            else $arg
            "/>

    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description[some $search-term in $search-terms-is satisfies matches(current(), $search-term, 'i')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="matched-terms" as="xs:string*" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="replacements" as="xs:string*" select="for $t in $matched-terms return $replace-terms[position() = index-of($search-terms-is, $t)]"/>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="functx:replace-multi(., $matched-terms, $replacements, 'i')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, you want to use XSLT so you need to write a template matching `description` elements matching your search text (you can pull in with `unparsed-text` from a file). As for not finding a function for case-insensitive matching, why does https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches with the `i` flag not work for you?

Comment: And as for special characters, if you have found http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_escape-for-regex.html you should be able to use it. The only problem is see with your input data is that is has line breaks while your search text doesn't seem to have them. But normalize-space might help.

Comment: @MartinHonnen ii have updated code, and removed the line breaks, whiich entered acciddentally. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to explain in more detail what the requirement is exactly, in your samples you have a single line each of search and replacement text, yet in your XSLT you seem to try to tokenize on lines and also seem to expect to possible have multiple matches for a single description. It is not clear to me how that can happen if you look for an exact match. So if the input data and the search/replacement task is more complicated than the current sample data suggests then please show us some examples.

Comment: The search file may have 100 lines. Each line may be found in the xml more than once. What i mean by an exact match, is the following <description>some text<\description> should be replaced, while <description>some text with more text<\description> should not be replaced, if we searched for some text. I will update the examples.

Comment: have updated the source file, search.txt, replacement.txt, and the expected output. Each line in the serach.txt file, may be found more than one times in the xml, so we need as many replacements as the occurrences of the line. It must be an exact match, which means if the node has the following: "text to be replaced, more text", and we search for "text to be replaced", the replacement in this node will not take place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your samples and explanation I think a single `description` element can only match once so I think your code will work fine with the following simplification:

```
<xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return concat('^', lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term)), '$')"/>

<xsl:template match="description[some $search-term in $search-terms-is satisfies matches(., $search-term, 'i')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="matched-term" as="xs:string" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replacement" as="xs:string" select="$replace-terms[index-of($search-terms-is, $matched-term)]"/>
        <xsl:value-of
            select="$replacement"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

As for a more complete example, here is one minus the external files:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs functx">

    <xsl:param name="search-text" as="xs:string">An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.
Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="replacement-text" as="xs:string">Value we need to store in the (description) element.
Another value we need to store in the (description) element.</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($search-text, '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:param name="search-terms-is" as="xs:string*" select="for $term in $search-terms return concat('^', lower-case(functx:escape-for-regex($term)), '$')"/>

    <xsl:param name="replace-terms" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($replacement-text, '\r?\n')"/>

    <xsl:include href="http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="description[some $search-term in $search-terms-is satisfies matches(., $search-term, 'i')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="matched-term" as="xs:string" select="$search-terms-is[matches(current(), ., 'i')]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="replacement" as="xs:string" select="$replace-terms[index-of($search-terms-is, $matched-term)]"/>
        <xsl:value-of
            select="$replacement"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/gVhD8RA.

Comment: in order for me to test, since it is not clear, could you please update the sample code to a full snippet? Thank you

Comment: I am sure you can test that on your own, simply replace that one line of the parameter as shown and replace that one template as shown. The rest of your stylesheet seems fine, except it seems you don't need the function `functx:replace-multi`.

Comment: I have added a complete XSLT stylesheet, of course in your real case you want to load the text for search and replacement from external files with `unparsed-text` but you already know how to do that so adapt those lines.

Comment: I really appreciate your will to help, thank you very much